# How to Query map in Groovy with sql?

Tags: sql, groovy

I am trying to query a map in Groovy using mysql using:

```
def dat = [["id": person[-1], "date" : appt]]          
dat.each{ db -> 
           sql.eachRow(
            "select * from ${Sql.expand(db)};", 
             { println "\t$db ${it.mid}"} );
```

but I get an error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=10886, date=19-01-2017}' at line 1
```

what seems to be the problem here?

---

************************************************* **EDIT** *****************************************************

I'm now trying to insert the map into a mysql, which I am then querying using:

```
  sql.execute '''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EDSS'''

  sql.execute '''
  CREATE TABLE EDSS (
    id          INT,
    Clinic   VARCHAR(15),
    EDSS    VARCHAR(64),
    item     VARCHAR(64)
  );
  '''


  sql.withBatch("INSERT INTO EDSS (id, Clinic, EDSS, item) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"){ bt ->
      bt.addBatch(df)
  } 
  def res = sql.eachRow("select * from EDSS"){ row ->
      println "$row"
  }
```

the `sql.eachRow` part works fine i.e. I can select, but in the the insert statement I only seem to be inserting the first row within the map i.e.

```
println(df):

[1025386, 20-10-2017, null, ahddkw9d9c]
[10213446, 19-04-2017, 2.5, null]
[102382, 19-04-2017, null, null]
[1628466, 19-04-2017, null, 292jdmd02d]
[1111345, 18-09-2015, unchanged, null]
```

but:

```
println(res):

[1025386, 20-10-2017, null, ahddkw9d9c]
```

---

*********************************** **Another EDIT** *****************************************************

So trying to loop round all the values in the map, df, with:

```
sql.withBatch { stmt ->
            df.each { k, v, x, y ->
                stmt.addBatch("INSERT INTO EDSS (study_id, Clinic, EDSS, NHS) VALUES ('$k', '$v', '$x', '$y')")
            }
      }
```

results in:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: sql$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure4.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [1025386]
```

I'm used to R where everything is nice and vectorized. If anyone can help at all that would be excellent!

Comment: What table are you expecting to select from?  `db` has the value `["id": person[-1], "date" : appt]` in the `each`, so goodness knows what `Sql.expand` will make of it...  Probably convert a string representation of a Map.

Comment: I was hoping I could dynamically query a map.

Comment: You can. But what you have is a list containing a map. What are you expecting the table name to be in your example?

Comment: Hi @tim_yates - I see you're point - I need a table to exist within the schema to select from it. Please see my edit where I am trying to insert the map into the database and then querying it afterwards.

Comment: For insert you have to iterate `bt` and add each item to batch.

Comment: @daggett - I have tried in another edit of the post.....and failed.

Comment: @brucezepplin, `k,v,x,y` ? should be just `k,v ->` because map contains keys and values...

Comment: @brucezepplin, if `df` array of arrays then `df.each{arr-> sql.addBatch(arr) }`. check for documentation how to work with batch: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#withBatch(int,java.lang.String,groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: I just get a NULL pointer exception when doing this ^^

Comment: @brucezepplin, null pointer it's another problem in your code. could you rework your question: add the initial data and describe what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What I observed here :**

You are trying to insert the **java.util.ArrayList** `[[val11, val12,...],[val21, val22,...]]`. you almost close at what you are trying to do.

Note : in comment **dagget** already mentioned this answer. I am just trying to show in code.

**Answer :**

```
def df = [
[1025386, '20-10-2017', null, 'ahddkw9d9c'],
[10213446, '19-04-2017', 2.5, null],
[102382, '19-04-2017', null, null],
[1628466,'19-04-2017', null, '292jdmd02d'],
[1111345, '18-09-2015', 'unchanged', null]
]
sql.withBatch("INSERT INTO EDSS (id, Clinic, EDSS, item) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"){ bt ->                      
    df.each { row ->
            bt.addBatch (row) // <==== Answer Line
    }
} 
sql.eachRow("select * from EDSS"){ row ->
        println "$row"
}
```

**Description :**

The variable `bt` is actually `BatchingPreparedStatementWrapper` object. See the [groovy document](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/BatchingPreparedStatementWrapper.html)

So the `addBatch()` method can accept these types `List<Object>` or `Object[]`.

**Output :**

```
[id:1025386, Clinic:20-10-2017, EDSS:[null], item:ahddkw9d9c]
[id:10213446, Clinic:19-04-2017, EDSS:2.5, item:[null]]
[id:102382, Clinic:19-04-2017, EDSS:[null], item:[null]]
[id:1628466, Clinic:19-04-2017, EDSS:[null], item:292jdmd02d]
[id:1111345, Clinic:18-09-2015, EDSS:unchanged, item:[null]]
```

Comment: Since @daggett posted the answer first in comments, I think he deserves to post an answer

Comment: @TarunLalwani. indeed. But he miserably put the `sql.addBatch()` instead of `bt.addBatch`. That is why i mentioned him and also i put the description in my answer what he tried to explain. I believe it is ok to answer here till he didn't.